# how can I enable the user download the whole application from the client side?

Tags: file, heroku, github, download, client

So, I have a web app hosted in heroku which is automatically updated when I update my github repository. I want to enable the user to **download the all the app files with their folders, images etc** as a zip from the client side so he can run it offline locally. I also want to add a file with user's comments to that zip before I force it to be downloaded on his browser.

I found a way to do it by redirecting him to github (but this will actually not redirect him there, it will just force a zip from github to be downloaded) :

```
window.location.replace("https://github.com/foo/FOO/archive/master.zip");
```

But this solution doesn't work for me because I want to **add to that zip an other file which will be created at the moment of the user download request**.

Does anyone have a solution to this?
Is there a way to do that by making requests to herokku to receive the files and using the jszip to pack them?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [web app caching](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). That way, the web app is accessed by the same URL as normal, but automatically falls back to a locally cached version if it cannot connect to the online app.

Comment: As a small note, while all modern browsers support web app caching, it has been deprecated and in favor of [service workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/), which are generally more powerful and fix some of the problems with web app caching. However, I doubt app caching support will disappear anytime soon.

Comment: @Frxstrem good point there about the web app caching, I hadn't checked out this, but not only as you say it is difficult to set it up, I also want to be able to load some files dynamically while user is browsing the app. So I think letting the user download the whole application is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using github's service, JSZipUtils and jszip. Here's the code for whom it might of help :

```
var content = null;  

JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("https://github.com/foo/FOO/archive/master.zip",   function(err, data) {
   if(err) {
     throw err; // or handle err
   }
   var zip = new JSZip(data);

   // to remove a not needed file
   zip.remove("CWAPP-master/abc.js");  

   // to add a custom file              
   zip.file('CWAPP-master/myClientSideFile.js',file);

   content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
   saveAs(content, 'myZip'); // force download

});
```